# Facing issue in using ember-light-table

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am learning ember js and I came across ember-light-table as an alternative of data-tables.

I just want to display some static data into table. So instead of creating mixin and component, I am writing code directly into route file. (Not sure things will work in this way or not).

Below is my route file

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import Table from 'ember-light-table';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Route.extend({
  table : null,
  columns: computed(function() {
    return [{
      label: 'Email',
      valuePath: 'email'
    }, {
      label: 'Name',
      valuePath: 'name'
    }];
  }),

  rows: computed(function() {
    return [{
      "email":"abc@gmail.email",
      "name":"Abc"
    }, {
        "email":"xyz@gmail.email",
        "name":"Xyz"
    }];
  }),

  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    let table = new Table(this.get('columns'),this.get('rows'));
    console.log("table = ",table);
    this.set('table', table);
  }
});
```

Template file

```
{{#light-table table height='65vh' as |t|}}
    {{t.head fixed=true }}

    {{#t.body canSelect=false as |body| }}
    {{/t.body}}
{{/light-table}}
```

I am getting below error in console:

> Error: Assertion Failed: [ember-light-table] table must be an instance of Table

I have seen code of document and other blog also, code seems identical, but not sure Am I missing something or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this in the router,  instead create a component.
Right now you have problem in your router as well, as there is no init hook in the router but you would like to use the init hook in the component.
Put all of your router code in the component, except the import router and extend router of course and the template in the component template. In your template that you use right now, call your component and that should fix the problem

Comment: Thanks for showing me right way to do this. I'll try to create component for this. :)